# DataTable Issue

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net, ole

```
  public class InnovationSubmission
    {
        public OleDbConnection connectr = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DatabaseTEST.accdr;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=DWPOIT");
        public OleDbDataAdapter Adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter();



        private List<SelectListItem> _Area = new List<SelectListItem>();
        private List<SelectListItem> _Team = new List<SelectListItem>();


        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a short description")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a detailed description")]
        public string DetailedDescription { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
        public string Originator { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
        [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+",
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
        public string OriginatorEmail { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SelectedArea { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SelectedTeam { get; set; }


        public List<SelectListItem> Area
        {
            get { return _Area; }
        }

        public List<SelectListItem> Teams
        {
            get 
            {

                string SQLSelect = ("SELECT * FROM Teams");
                OleDbCommand sCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQLSelect, connectr);
                Adaptor.SelectCommand = sCommand;


                connectr.Open();
                Adaptor.Fill(areaTable);
                connectr.Dispose();

                foreach (DataRow row in areaTable.Rows)
                {
                    _Team.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = row[1].ToString(), Value = row[1].ToString() });

                }

                return _Team;
            }
        }

        public DataTable areaTable = new DataTable();


        }
}
```

Comment: What is `connector`? (Note that doing a database fetch operation on a property access is pretty smelly. Also you should use a `using` statement, and a fresh connection each time.)

Comment: Its an OledBconnection object, i want to utilise the Datatable in 2 other different parts of this particular class when i create a new instance of the class.

Comment: Sure the connection isnt left open somewhere else?

Comment: Its the only segment opening a connection.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `connector.Dispose()` and within a `using` block?

Comment: At what line do you get the error ?

Comment: And can we get connector declaration please

Comment: If this is the only section using the connector, why isnt it defined here? where you can be sure whats happened to it..

Comment: I have two  private List<SelectListItem>() objects that need to convert form the 2 columns in the datatabe, into SelectListItems(), I was trying to get the Datatable setup so that each getter for the other two objects could access it when the CLass object is created, I guess i'm going about this all wrong! :-(

Comment: have you tried putting connectr.Open() before passing it to sCommand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you have a problem with the connector object. Probably it's used somewhere else and that's why you get the exception. Open new connection, do the query and close it. Try using `using` to achieve that and query within the using block.

Also, as already mentioned in comments - it's not a very good idea to do a db query in a property getter. Looks weird and hacky...

Answer (score -1):

If i use it like this it is fine!

```
 public List<SelectListItem> Teams
        {
            get 
            {

                string SQLSelect = ("SELECT * FROM Teams");
                OleDbCommand sCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQLSelect, connector);
                Adaptor.SelectCommand = sCommand;


                connector.Open();
                Adaptor.Fill(areaTable);
                connector.Dispose();

                foreach (DataRow row in areaTable.Rows)
                {
                    _Team.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = row[1].ToString(), Value = row[1].ToString() });

                }

                return _Team;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should just update your question if you want to provide more info instead of answering it. I'm sure the problem is within Connector or where you declare connector. Could you move that part in your question and add the connector i'm sure you'll get the answer your'e looking for.